# プロフィールページが新しくなりました

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, デザイン

4月15日に英語版でプロフィールページがリニューアルされました。

英語版のブログ記事: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/

- 自己紹介目的に特化した「プロフィール」と活動状況を確認しやすい「アクティビティ」に分割
- 自分の影響力を可視化！

<del>翻訳の確認を兼ね、現在日本語版メタで新プロフィールページをテスト中です。</del>

5/21追記：メインサイトにも適用しました。

表示崩れや翻訳がおかしいところなどあれば、この質問への回答か[チャット](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)でご指摘ください。

Answer (score 2):

プロフィールのところで「あなたの［自分について］は現在空白です」と表示されいますが、「あなたの自己紹介は現在未記入です」ではどうでしょうか？

Comment: [Transifex上で更新しました](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289162?q=your%20about%20me%20is%20currently)。多分そのうち反映されます。

Answer (score 1):

未訳色々

### アクティビティ

- タグバッジをクリックしたときの[Gold/Silver/Bronze <del>・獲得条件</del>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8voze.png)
- <del>好奇心バッジで[「回答しましょう」](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBbC9.png)をクリックすると質問ページに飛ぶ（回答しましょう、が適切でない）</del>
  `days asked` `positive question record` 等々も未訳
- 「目標にするバッジを選択」の [recommended <del>・獲得条件</del>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfOa5.png)

### 設定

- <del>サイドバーの[Edit Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Mgf.png)</del>
- 誕生日のプレースホルダ `YYYY/MM/DD, only used for displaying age`
- <del>基本設定: ニュースレターの説明文 `Sign up for a weekly email with .....`</del>
- コミュニティの公開設定: 説明文にMarkdownが適用されていない
  `**これはあなたの活動を完全に隠すわけではありません。**`